# I have 2 lambda functions using BOTO 3. I want to combine both in one expression so the output of fun1 can be used by fun2 to generate a message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm a newbie at lambda and python, so i thought i'd ask here since i was able to find ton of help here in building 2 functions that needed to communicate between a commercial acct and a gov acct.

My 2 functions work as they should. I've tested them both separately. However, I'm trying to or need to combine both (currently reading about nested or helper functions) or grab the return/output of function 1(a presigned s3 url) to be used by function 2 to create a sqs message with the url to send over to the queue where another lambda will then grab and process it.

Here's my code:

Fn 1:

```py
def s3_url_generator(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=7200):
    get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = 'mybucket'
    object_name = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
    last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(object_name, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0]
    try:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': last_added},
                                               ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

# The response contains the presigned URL

    return url
```

Fn 2:

```py
def sqs_message_generator(queue_url, message_body):
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    sqs_config = Config(region_name='us-gov-west-1', signature_version='v4')
    sqs = session.client('sqs', config=sqs_config)
    queue_url = "http://my-sqs-url"
    message_body = {"some message"}
    send_message = sqs.send_message(QueueUrl=queue_url, MessageBody=json.dumps(message_body))
    return {'statusCode': send_message["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"], 'body': json.dumps(send_message)}
```

Any suggestions, pointers or help will certainly be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I've tried, but failed to improve the formatting of your code. Please improve the indentation.

Comment: Will do. I think there's an extra few lines that got copied over twice.

Comment: What specific issue are you having? They just look like Python functions -- they are not actually AWS Lambda functions. You could simply call the first function, then pass the return value as `queue_url` to the second function. I'm not sure why the second function has hard-coded credentials -- Lambda functions obtain credentials by assigning an IAM Role and should never need to hard-code them.

Comment: Yes, the reason to the credentials is due to the fact you can't assume a role from commercial when one resource, in this case lambda, need to access a resource in gov cloud. This will need to be worked a different way for now for testing I have hard coded as it needs to use a user in order to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are after code like this:

```py
url = s3_url_generator(bucket_name, object_name)
if url:
    result = sqs_message_generator(url, message_body)
    # check what was returned from result
```

The first line gives the url returned from s3 the name `url`. This is checked to see if there was the `ClientError` exception. If not, the url can be used in the next function. The return value from that function is given the name `result`.